# strange problems on cd-rom writers

Tags: linux, data-cd, burning

I have a really strange problems with my last 5 burners. They look all broken.
They can read the files on CDs but when I burn a cd it seem that the burning was gone well, but when I try to md5 the media:

```
md5sum /dev/sr0
```

Linux sometimes give me the following error:

```
Input/Output error
```

Or sometime it simply give me a **wrong** md5.

If I make a:

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 > cicco.iso
```

the two images (the original one and the burned one) have different size.
For example the openbsd install cd is:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root    root    222334976  2 set 17.40 cicco.iso
-rw-rw-r--. 1 argento argento 222330880 27 ago 12.55 install53.iso
```

the cicco is the burned iso (dd) and the install53 is the original.
If I burn the iso with an other pc it works well. I mean the cd and the image gave me the same md5 on my pc with the broken burner.
My opinion is that I have a virus that have flashed the firmware with corrupted one.
That's really strange that all 5 burnera are all broken. Also I am sure that when I bought the lastone it was working well for the first 1 or 2 weeks.
If u look the iso images you see that cicco.iso is much larger than the original.
And following are the differences:

```
@@ -13895678,259 +13895678,3 @@
 d407fd0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
 d407fe0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
 d407ff0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................

-d408000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
...........
-d408820: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
-d408830: 0000 0000 0000 2400 0000 0000 0000 0000  ......$.........
-d408840: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
...
-d4089c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
-d4089d0: 0000 002f 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .../............
-d4089e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
.............
-d408ab0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
-d408ac0: 0000 0000 0000 6100 0000 0000 0000 b915  ......a.........
-d408ad0: 0000 0000 0000 65a8 0000 0000 0000 3900  ......e.......9.
-d408ae0: 0000 0000 0000 527a 0000 0000 0000 e6f7  ......Rz........
-d408af0: 0000 0000 0000 1100 0000 0000 0000 71ff  ..............q.
-d408b00: 0000 0000 0000 34ab 0000 0000 0000 8800  ......4.........
-d408b10: 0000 0000 0000 afab 0000 0000 0000 bd31  ...............1
-d408b20: 0000 0000 0000 3d2f 0000 0000 0000 82b1  ......=/........
-d408b30: 0000 0000 0000 ae8f 0000 0000 0000 9edc  ................
-d408b40: 0000 0000 0000 2a9b 0000 0000 0000 d320  ......*........ 
-d408b50: 0000 0000 0000 2c62 0000 0000 0000 0366  ......,b.......f
-d408b60: 0000 0000 0000 d2f9 0000 0000 0000 aad8  ................
-d408b70: 0000 0000 0000 7a3b 0000 0000 0000 e9da  ......z;........
-d408b80: 0000 0000 0000 7891 0000 0000 0000 14c9  ......x.........
-d408b90: 0000 0000 4e00 443e 0000 0000 0000 4891  ....N.D>......H.
-d408ba0: 0000 0000 0000 8d74 0000 0000 8000 db7b  .......t.......{
-d408bb0: 0000 0000 0000 9dc5 0000 0000 0000 6093  ..............`.
-d408bc0: 0000 0000 fa00 feaf 0000 0000 0000 443d  ..............D=
-d408bd0: 0000 0000 0000 af26 0000 0000 fd00 b6bb  .......&........
-d408be0: 0000 0000 0000 660e 0000 0000 0000 8dc5  ......f.........
-d408bf0: 0000 0000 81c5 9df9 0000 0000 0000 75c3  ..............u.
-d408c00: 0000 0000 0000 502b 0000 0000 2bc6 9ebe  ......P+....+...
-d408c10: 0000 0000 0000 9f1f 0000 0000 0000 5698  ..............V.
-d408c20: 0000 0000 fa7e 1dd7 0000 0000 0000 44e8  .....~........D.
-d408c30: 0000 0000 0000 9ed7 0000 0000 a947 aea5  .............G..
-d408c40: 0000 0000 0000 ffb3 0000 0000 cf00 19c7  ................
-d408c50: 0000 0000 020f b6e6 0000 0000 0000 8d44  ...............D
-d408c60: 0000 0000 a800 103c 0000 0000 2956 fdcf  .......<....)V..
-d408c70: 0000 0000 0000 306f 0000 0000 c900 ce95  ......0o........
-d408c80: 0000 0000 b960 c9dd 0000 0000 0000 01a7  .....`..........
-d408c90: 0000 0000 0d00 4b4f 0000 0000 7661 bb03  ......KO....va..
-d408ca0: 0000 0000 0000 3803 0000 0000 79e8 3072  ......8.....y.0r
-d408cb0: 0000 0000 9cf6 51d3 0000 0000 0000 e6b1  ......Q.........
-d408cc0: 0000 0000 6fcf af21 0000 0000 fbc7 3b7e  ....o..!......;~
-d408cd0: 0000 0000 0000 9da4 0000 0000 7aae edf3  ............z...
-d408ce0: 0000 0000 ab47 cdd2 0000 0000 0000 fe88  .....G..........
-d408cf0: 0000 0000 701f 07f3 0000 0000 348c c826  ....p.......4..&
-d408d00: 0000 0000 db00 4ab4 0000 0700 bdcf f04c  ......J........L
-d408d10: 0000 0000 056d 8300 0000 0000 8f00 0871  .....m.........q
-d408d20: 0000 0000 91a7 61a1 0000 0000 b461 b762  ......a......a.b
-d408d30: 0000 0000 c100 4990 0000 0000 62dc 945f  ......I.....b.._
-d408d40: 0000 0000 8998 a6da 0000 0000 d500 7057  ..............pW
-d408d50: 0019 0000 5c74 2021 0000 0000 bb09 335a  ....\t !......3Z
-d408d60: 0000 0000 4bb3 f9c0 0000 0000 cb7a cf6e  ....K........z.n
-d408d70: 0000 0000 f839 8292 0000 0000 93f5 baf8  .....9..........
-d408d80: 0000 0000 c971 734c 0000 0000 1b42 8b71  .....qsL.....B.q
-d408d90: 0000 0000 0de7 69d0 7700 0000 5df8 d6c3  ......i.w...]...
-d408da0: 0000 0000 56b9 fef2 0000 0000 188b ddcf  ....V...........
-d408db0: 0000 0000 8631 3285 0000 0000 c812 d68d  .....12.........
-d408dc0: 0000 0000 9451 5076 0000 0000 c483 137b  .....QPv.......{
-d408dd0: 0000 0000 e726 ca9a 0000 0000 c40c 36ae  .....&........6.
-d408de0: 0000 0000 ece5 4dfc 0000 0000 5e98 386a  ......M.....^.8j
-d408df0: 0000 0000 03b3 c9b4 0000 0000 a0f9 f83d  ...............=
-d408e00: 0000 0000 787d e2a1 0000 0000 8e3e bf13  ....x}.......>..
-d408e10: 0000 0000 9f9c 2831 0000 0000 7aac 233d  ......(1....z.#=
-d408e20: 0000 0000 fda1 ef4a 0000 0000 8f1e e408  .......J........
-d408e30: 0000 0000 f6a5 86fb 0000 0000 f58a 430d  ..............C.
-d408e40: 0000 0000 237d d9e1 0000 0000 af4e fc34  ....#}.......N.4
-d408e50: 0000 0000 3b77 7b52 0000 0000 b2c8 7596  ....;w{R......u.
-d408e60: 0000 0000 4329 f1de 0000 0000 f60a 3189  ....C)........1.
-d408e70: 0000 0000 d82f 1a9c 0000 0000 d2b8 5db2  ...../........].
-d408e80: 0000 0000 3565 9722 0000 0000 e5ef 0b0c  ....5e."........
-d408e90: 0000 0000 11b5 cc77 0000 0000 e445 0b42  .......w.....E.B
-d408ea0: 0000 0000 79bb 62f3 0000 0000 0c49 c5f6  ....y.b......I..
-d408eb0: 0000 0000 d90c 9aec 0000 0000 8c33 25d5  .............3%.
-d408ec0: 0000 0000 0b76 8766 0000 0000 165d 0ec4  .....v.f.....]..
-d408ed0: 0000 0000 f1e1 8448 0000 0000 feca c057  .......H.......W
-d408ee0: 0000 0000 65cc 2b15 0000 0000 0a97 472e  ....e.+.......G.
-d408ef0: 0000 0000 e73e ca90 0000 0000 3369 9c2e  .....>......3i..
-d408f00: 0000 0000 f45a c77b 0000 0000 f5b2 c735  .....Z.{.......5
-d408f10: 0000 0000 9dbc 69b1 0000 0000 75f2 a705  ......i.....u...
-d408f20: 0000 3a00 d5d8 5f1a 0000 0000 55a2 bf39  ..:..._.....U..9
-d408f30: 0000 0000 8745 a2b3 0000 f900 1d86 89a2  .....E..........
-d408f40: 0000 0000 e711 8a8c 0000 0000 0f2b 441f  .............+D.
-d408f50: 0000 a400 9b06 eb42 0000 0000 6f5b 6c3b  .......B....o[l;
-d408f60: 0000 0000 eda9 8dbe 0000 b200 3757 56be  ............7WV.
-d408f70: 0000 0000 2433 5b55 0000 0000 01e8 004e  ....$3[U.......N
-d408f80: 0000 0d85 680e ae84 0000 0000 e84e ceb4  ....h........N..
-d408f90: 0000 0000 a02a f81f 0000 02e3 807a e023  .....*.......z.#
-d408fa0: 0000 0000 d2e7 1d8a 0000 0000 9ac3 2b11  ..............+.
-d408fb0: 0000 3265 fa97 032e 0000 0000 e83a ce93  ..2e.........:..
-d408fc0: 0000 0000 942d af5d 0000 7abc f45d 8779  .....-.]..z..].y
-d408fd0: 0000 0000 82f2 e185 0000 6a00 dafe db00  ..........j.....
-d408fe0: 0000 61a8 1364 0deb 0000 0000 25db 5b1b  ..a..d......%.[.
-d408ff0: 0000 1800 69e6 aeca 0000 a133 8040 6030  ....i......3.@`0
```

What are your opinions ? Could be really a virus ??

Comment: Can you try to disable switching to higher speed during burning?

Comment: Almost certainly not malware under the "hear hoofbeats, think horses not zebras" principle. See the answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Linux sometimes give me the following error: 
>   Input/Output error

This indicates that some block of the medium is
not readable and the drive could not correct its
errors.

In the most harmless case, the CD was written
by write type TAO, and Linux runs into its long
standing "readahead bug". This happens at the very
end of CD reading.

In less harmless case, the medium has a bad block
where valuable data should be recorded.

> Or sometime it simply give me a wrong md5.

Many types of optical media deliver more bytes than 
were written by the most recent burn run.
To avoid the Linux readahead bug, the burn programs
often add a few hundred kB of zeros in order
to push the bug into unimportant regions of the CD.

To verify the freshly burnt content of your CD you
have to truncate the data stream from the CD to the
size of the ISO image which you have written.

Determine the number of 2KB blocks of the original ISO:

```
blocks=$(expr $(du -b install53.iso | awk '{print $1}') / 2048)
```

Read that amount from CD and pipe it into md5sum:

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=2048 count=$blocks | md5sum
```

If the burn run went well, this must yield the same MD5 as

```
md5sum install53.iso
```

---

If dd with the correct number of blocks produces i/o error
within the last 128 KB of the image, then it is worthwhile
to try a reader that does not use the Linux block device
driver. E.g. my program xorriso:

```
xorriso -indev /dev/sr0 -check_media data_to=cicco.iso --
```

Depending on the medium type and burn program, this might
read too many data, too. So again use for MD5 computation

```
dd if=cicco.iso bs=2048 count=$blocks | md5sum
```

Comment: ok, it looks work.
but in **/var/log/messages** I have:


      sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Unhandled sense code

    sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
    Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
    sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
    Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
    sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
    Add. Sense: Timeout on logical unit
    sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
    Read(10): 28 00 00 01 a7 f8 00 00 1a 00
    end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 434144
    quiet_error: 3 callbacks suppressed
    Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 54268


other 9 lines

Comment: `Sense Key : Hardware Error ... Add. Sense: Timeout on logical unit` means that the drive gave up on the read attempt. This is a problem of the drive and possibly the medium. If this happens too often, then you need a new drive.

Answer (score 0):

Tools like [wodim](https://wiki.debian.org/BurnCd), [cdrecord](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/CD-Writing-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.1), or [brasero](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=brasero) are usually suggested for CD-ROM burning under Debian. These applications have more complete handling of burn speed, readback, and device specific ioctls that `dd` lacks.

You are looking more at limitations of the fact that CD burning is a post-design kludge than any fundamental, fixable problems with the raw device driver available to dd. If your CD-ROM were a magtape, dd would have no problems (although magtapes are traditionally harder to listen to in your car).

Answer (score -1):

The difference is exactly 4096 bytes, could be an additionnal MBR? (use fdisk on the device and see what you get)

It could also be due to a particular format differing from the original used in the .iso.

Check the burning options.

Answer (score -1):

As @msw has suggested, you're better off creating the ISO of a CD/DVD using an actual tool, using `dd` like this can be problematic. Especially if there is a defect in the media. `dd` will do nothing to attempt to repair this.

If it's a DVD I often times enlist the help of `dvdbackup` which has been excellent at making copies of DVDs that `k3b` would duplicate, but then be unplayable. When I've investigated these in the past, the DVD was often times scratched or defective but still playable. `dvdbackup` was able to duplicate these without issue.

These are the steps that I've used in the past to run `dvdbackup`:

```
$ cd /dir/where/you/save/the/dvd

# insert DVD to be copied
$ dvdbackup -M
$ genisoimage -dvd-video -udf -o movie.iso /dir/where/you/save/the/dvd
$ eject /dev/dvd
```

#### References

- [dvdbackup](http://dvdbackup.sourceforge.net/)
- [[one-liner]: How to Backup a Movie DVD via the Command Line on Fedora 14 & CentOS 5](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/7325/one-liner-how-to-backup-a-movie-dvd-via-the-command-line-on-fedora-14-centos-5/)